# How to add footer to the list box in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox, footer

I'm doing one windows phone 8 application. In this I've used list box. For the very first page I'm getting the data from server and adding that data to list box. Now I want to add **Show More** at the bottom of the list box i.e after the last item, to get the next items from the server.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Hear you have to  use Horizontal scrolling for load next data

**Check below tutorial**

[Detect when a ListBox scrolls to its end (WP7)](http://blog.slimcode.com/2010/09/11/detect-when-a-listbox-scrolls-to-its-end-wp7/)

[Windows phone tutorial:Listbox](http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/)

[WP7 – How To Extend ListBox When Reaching Last Item](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/04/06/wp7-how-to-extend-listbox-when-reaching-last-item.aspx)

[Windows Phone 7 ListBox Pagination with MVVMLight & ApplicationBar](http://indyfromoz.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/windows-phone-7-listbox-pagination-with-mvvmlight-applicationbar/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 we can Gets or sets the amount of data to fetch for virtualizing/prefetch operations by using 
 ListViewBase.DataFetchSize property and can Initiates the asynchronous request to load more data items, in accordance with the active incremental loading settings by ListViewBase.LoadMoreItemsAsync method.

If you want to do it by pagination then the following links may be helpfull for you
 DataFetchSize method
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.datafetchsize.aspx

```
LoadMoreItemsAsync method:
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.loadmoreitemsasync.aspx

```
You can see examples of using these here (though note that the sample was based on Windows 8 BUILD release and the apis have had some changes)
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/e71b7036-4fb7-4963-a65d-5bcb9fd8f664

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead posting the logic as My code might not match with yours

So

1 -> Save the server data in an array or a list.
2 -> Design the xaml in a way that the Parent Grid has two or more rows with the last row for the show more. And the one before for the list. (Adjust height accordingly)
3 -> Populate it with a limited amount of data.
4 -> Next use the `ListBox.Items.Add(data)` method to add the data to the list. Keep sorted property off so that the elements are inserted at the bottom of the list
 -> Go through the link [Add Method for Observable Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add.aspx)

Use step four on the show more button click .. and also adjust the height of the list or put it into a scrollviewer so that limited height scrolling can be done . olease update if further queries